# Laravel form validation request unique ignorant doesn't work on update

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to update a data which has a unique name required on validation. However, I can't get it to work because it keep telling me that `The name has already been taken.`. Already tried the

Please have a look at my validation script:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class RequestDepartment extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'division_id' => 'required|numeric',
            'name' => "sometimes|required|string|unique:departments,name,{$this->id},id",
            'description' => 'sometimes|nullable|string'
        ];
    }
}
```

also, my controller's update script:

```php
/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \App\Http\Requests\RequestDepartment  $request
 * @param  \App\Department  $department
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(RequestDepartment $request, Department $department)
{
    $department->update($request->validated());
    $department = Department::whereId($department->id)->with('division')->first();

    return response()->json([
        'updated' => true,
        'data' => $department,
    ]);
}
```

I'm using Laravel 7.x, any idea please?

**EDIT**

I want to update the `division_id` or `description` field.

**EDIT 2**

My form is dynamic, inside Vue instance and `Form` class

```js
data() {
  return {
    form: new Form({
      division_id: "",
      company_id: "",
      name: "",
      description: ""
    }),
    updateForm: new Form({
      division_id: "",
      company_id: "",
      name: "",
      description: ""
    }),
    filter: ""
  };
},
```

Comment: I don't sure, but `sometimes` with `require`, and I know that documentation use this case... but its strangely

Comment: `sometimes` and `required` means that if the `name` field is provided, it should be required and must be validated. In this case, I already tell the framework to skip the given `id` no matter what, I compared it on the older project using laravel `6.x` and it works. maybe there is a change on `7.x`?

Comment: if u want to update `division_id` or `description` and u don't need `name` just create a new `RequestUpdateDepartment`

Comment: and if `required` will not be set, it will not validate `name` field?. I'm still on 5.8 and didn't know about new features.

Comment: it is validated but not `required`, you can insert a `NULL` or an empty string on it

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```
'name' => "required|string|unique:departments,name,". $id,
```

Here $id means wchich id you want to update. this will check unique portion all  name data but not for this id.

Comment: thanks, but `$id` is undefined, I am using form request validator, not hardcoding it in the controller

Comment: i just say $id ..you use your dynamic id...for this .....which id you need to update

Comment: i tried that, nothing happen. it is just the same as witing it like `"{$this-id}"`

Comment: He puts `id` in post body, mb he need to take it with `$request->input('id')` ?

Comment: My mistake, it should be `company_id`,  i did changed it, still not working.. :/